# Why does ListView break Column when using childrenRect to specify it's dimensions?

Tags: qt, qml

The title says it all. Here are two examples one using `childrenRect` to specify it's dimensions and one doesn't.

With `childrenRect`:

```
Column {
    width: 400
    height: 600

    ListView {
        width: childrenRect.width
        height: childrenRect.height

        model: 2

        delegate: Text {
            text: "some text"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: 400
        height: 20
        color: "black"
    }
}
```

Without `childrenRect`:

```
Column {
    width: 400
    height: 600

    ListView {
        width: 400
        height: 100

        model: 2

        delegate: Text {
            text: "some text"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: 400
        height: 20
        color: "black"
    }
}
```

When running the first code, my `Rectangle` overlaps the `ListView`, why? Is this because, `ListView` will calculate it's dimension only after `Column` draws itself? How could I over come this?

One solution which works is to set the `Rectangle` `anchor.top` to the `ListView` `anchors.bottom`. Is there any other or better (?) solution?

Comment: Try with `height: contentHeight` in the ListView

Comment: Thanks it works! If you would create an answer I would accept that. Also if you know why is this behavior you could add that to your answer also.